# How do I read S3 credentials from a different file name (not called credentials in .aws)?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, aws-credentials

I am able to upload an object from my local to my cloud S3 bucket when reading from the "credentials" located in .aws however there is a file that is the same format as "credentials" called "tester" for the sake of this  question and I cannot get it to read from it, even though it's the exact same copy as credentials.

If I do this:

```
# Upload the file
        s3_client = boto3.client(
            's3',
            aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
            aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
            aws_session_token=SESSION_TOKEN,
        )
```

what should I be putting in ACCESS_KEY,SECRET_KEY,SESSION_TOKEN? I do not want to hardcode my credentials but I want it to not read from credentials in .aws but from another file instead called "tester" which has the same credentials.

Note: The "tester" file is in the same location as my python/Boto3 program on my Mac.

Comment: I also noticed that almost all your questions have answers, yet not a single one accepted. Accepting good answers is not only a good practice, but it reduces number of duplicates and increases chances for your questions to be actually answered.

Comment: I will accept from now on. No problem.

Comment: Thanks. You can revisit past questions and answers and accepted those that were helpful retrospectively.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set [AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html) env variable before you run your code, or in python itself, to specify new configuration file.

Comment: I have heard that there are parameters you pass into the boto3.client or boto3.resource functions that let you specify the access key and secret key. So how can I read the "tester" file this way? Is  setting the env variable the only  way?

Comment: @IBSurviver Yes, I think its the only way. At least I am not aware of other options in boto3 to do that.

Comment: technically you can still do this in code. just update the `os.environ` with the new file name in your script. no need to figure out if boto3 supports it :-)

Comment: @rv.kvetch Yes, that's right and that's why I wrote "or in python itself".